# = in URL changes into %3D

Tags: html, url

I have url with parameters in my static web page

https://www.nejlepsi-skolky.cz/list-map-of-kindergartens-seznam-mapa-skolek-jesli?locationFrom=Velk%C3%A9%20Opatovice,Dlouh%C3%A1%20429;latFrom=49.6120414733887;lonFrom=16.6786785125732

the problem is that the second and the third equals signs are changed into %3D, when I click on the URL. Is there a possibility to say to the browser not to change equals? And why the first equal works fine?

I have found some answers about [nginx][1], but this is just static site not connected to nginx settings.
Thank you

Comment: Those `=` are supposed to be part of the value of `locationFrom`? Then they *must* be encoded like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused with saving the page to the local disk. During the save the & signs are being changed by firefox into ; signs

Answer (score 3):

> the problem is that the second and the third equals signs are changed into %3D, when I click on the URL.

This is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). It should not be a problem if you are reading the URL with something that supports the standards.

> And why the first equal works fine?

The standard format of a query string is a series of `key=value` pairs which are separated by `&` characters.

Older versions of the standard supported `;` as well as `&`, but they are obsolete.

`=` signs, being the symbol that indicates the end of a key and start of a value, should be encoded as `%3D` when they occur inside a key or a value.

The first equal in your example is the symbol that separates the key from the value. The second is data inside the value.

> Is there a possibility to say to the browser not to change equals?

Change your URL so you use `&` as the separator instead of `;`.

Comment: Ok when "The standard format of a query string is a series of key=value pairs which are separated by & (or, less commonly, ;) characters."    why browser do not parse more keys?

Comment: @Puser — Please see the edit made before you posted that comment.